# PHP PDO doesn't go to catch block when trigger has raiserror

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, triggers

I'm working at an php application. When an error occurs by a sql server trigger (raiserror) the PDO try catch block doesn't go to the catch.

// Raiserror in the trigger, it works because i tested it in MSSQL management studio

```
RAISERROR('Een niet Europees project hoeft geen Projectrol te hebben.', 16, 1)
```

// The try catch block in php

```
try {
            $res = verbindDatabase()->prepare($stmt)->execute($valueArray);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e){
            //echo $e->getMessage();
            header('Location: index.php?tabel='.$tabelNaam.'&actie=Error');
            exit();
        }
```

// Code doesn't go to the catch block when the trigger is triggered

Expected result is the code going to the catch block.

Comment: catch `\Exception` instead ... and see if RAISERROR throws.

Comment: `$`verbindDatabase() ???

Comment: verbindDatabase() is a made function to connect to the database, its Dutch ;p

Comment: Did you call the method `setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` on your PDO object? http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php You should do it just after `new \PDO(...);`

Comment: yes
$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Comment: first, Try with: `setAttribute(\ PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true)`. Why? With some drivers, PDO can get 'confused' with certain errors and not convert them to 'exceptions'. ;-/ Also, while debugging, test for errors error explicitly after each command and show the error message if it happens.